# How to find and modify field in nested case classes?

Tags: scala, lenses, monocle-scala

Defined some nested case classes with `List` fields:

```
@Lenses("_") case class Version(version: Int, content: String)
@Lenses("_") case class Doc(path: String, versions: List[Version])
@Lenses("_") case class Project(name: String, docs: List[Doc])
@Lenses("_") case class Workspace(projects: List[Project])
```

And a sample `workspace`:

```
val workspace = Workspace(List(
  Project("scala", List(
    Doc("src/a.scala", List(Version(1, "a11"), Version(2, "a22"))),
    Doc("src/b.scala", List(Version(1, "b11"), Version(2, "b22"))))),
  Project("java", List(
    Doc("src/a.java", List(Version(1, "a11"), Version(2, "a22"))),
    Doc("src/b.java", List(Version(1, "b11"), Version(2, "b22"))))),
  Project("javascript", List(
    Doc("src/a.js", List(Version(1, "a11"), Version(2, "a22"))),
    Doc("src/b.js", List(Version(1, "b11"), Version(2, "b22")))))
))
```

Now I want to write such a method, which add a new `version` to a `doc`:

```
def addNewVersion(workspace: Workspace, projectName: String, docPath: String, version: Version): Workspace = {
  ???
}
```

I will be used as following:

```
  val newWorkspace = addNewVersion(workspace, "scala", "src/b.scala", Version(3, "b33"))

  println(newWorkspace == Workspace(List(
    Project("scala", List(
      Doc("src/a.scala", List(Version(1, "a11"), Version(2, "a22"))),
      Doc("src/b.scala", List(Version(1, "b11"), Version(2, "b22"), Version(3, "b33"))))),
    Project("java", List(
      Doc("src/a.java", List(Version(1, "a11"), Version(2, "a22"))),
      Doc("src/b.java", List(Version(1, "b11"), Version(2, "b22"))))),
    Project("javascript", List(
      Doc("src/a.js", List(Version(1, "a11"), Version(2, "a22"))),
      Doc("src/b.js", List(Version(1, "b11"), Version(2, "b22")))))
  )))
```

I'm not sure how to implement it in an elegant way. I tried with [monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle), but it doesn't provide `filter` or `find`. My awkward solution is:

```
def addNewVersion(workspace: Workspace, projectName: String, docPath: String, version: Version): Workspace = {
  (_projects composeTraversal each).modify(project => {
    if (project.name == projectName) {
      (_docs composeTraversal each).modify(doc => {
        if (doc.path == docPath) {
          _versions.modify(_ ::: List(version))(doc)
        } else doc
      })(project)
    } else project
  })(workspace)
}
```

Is there any better solution? (Can use any libraries, not only `monocle`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just extended [Quicklens](https://github.com/adamw/quicklens) with the `eachWhere` method to handle such a scenario, this particular method would look like this:

```
import com.softwaremill.quicklens._

def addNewVersion(workspace: Workspace, projectName: String, docPath: String, version: Version): Workspace = {
  workspace
    .modify(_.projects.eachWhere(_.name == projectName)
             .docs.eachWhere(_.path == docPath).versions)
    .using(vs => version :: vs)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

We can implement `addNewVersion` with optics quite nicely but there is a gotcha:

```
import monocle._
import monocle.macros.Lenses
import monocle.function._
import monocle.std.list._ 
import Workspace._, Project._, Doc._

def select[S](p: S => Boolean): Prism[S, S] =
   Prism[S, S](s => if(p(s)) Some(s) else None)(identity)

 def workspaceToVersions(projectName: String, docPath: String): Traversal[Workspace, List[Version]] =
  _projects composeTraversal each composePrism select(_.name == projectName) composeLens
    _docs composeTraversal each composePrism select(_.path == docPath) composeLens
    _versions

def addNewVersion(workspace: Workspace, projectName: String, docPath: String, version: Version): Workspace =
  workspaceToVersions(projectName, docPath).modify(_ :+ version)(workspace)
```

This will work but you might have noticed the use of `select` `Prism` which is not provided by [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle). This is because `select` does not satisfy `Traversal` laws that state that for all `t`, `t.modify(f) compose t.modify(g) == t.modify(f compose g)`.

A counter example is:

```
val negative: Prism[Int, Int] = select[Int](_ < 0)
(negative.modify(_ + 1) compose negative.modify(_ - 1))(-1) == 0
```

However, the usage of `select` in `workspaceToVersions` is completely valid because we filter on a different field that we modify. So we cannot invalidate the predicate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Monocle's `Index` type to make your solution cleaner and more generic.

```
import monocle._, monocle.function.Index, monocle.function.all.index

def indexListBy[A, B, I](l: Lens[A, List[B]])(f: B => I): Index[A, I, B] =
  new Index[A, I, B] {
    def index(i: I): Optional[A, B] = l.composeOptional(
      Optional((_: List[B]).find(a => f(a) == i))(newA => as =>
        as.map {
          case a if f(a) == i => newA
          case a => a
        }
      )
    )
  }

implicit val projectNameIndex: Index[Workspace, String, Project] =
  indexListBy(Workspace._projects)(_.name)

implicit val docPathIndex: Index[Project, String, Doc] =
  indexListBy(Project._docs)(_.path)
```

This says: I know how to look up a project in a workspace using a string (the name), and a doc in a project by a string (the path). You could also put `Index` instances like `Index[List[Project], String, Project]`, but since you don't own `List` that's arguably not ideal.

Next you can define an `Optional` that combines the two lookups:

```
def docLens(projectName: String, docPath: String): Optional[Workspace, Doc] =
  index[Workspace, String, Project](projectName).composeOptional(index(docPath))
```

And then your method:

```
def addNewVersion(
  workspace: Workspace,
  projectName: String,
  docPath: String,
  version: Version
): Workspace =
  docLens(projectName, docPath).modify(doc =>
    doc.copy(versions = doc.versions :+ version)
  )(workspace)
```

And you're done. This isn't really more concise than your implementation, but it's made up of more nicely composable pieces.